# How to access a shared file from multiple sites on the same server

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

I have a dedicated server with a fair few sites running.   I have a file I'd like to share from one site to all of the others using a php include.   I know URL includes are turned off for good reason so is there any secure way to share the file?

i.e. site1 has the file at http://www.site.com/shared_file/share.php

I want to be able to access it from Sites 2,3,4,5 etc using

```
<?php include ("/home/site/public_html/shared_file/share.php");?>
```

Any ideas?  At the moment I get a permission denied error.   The server is running WHM and CPanel (latest versions).

Thanks
Brett

Answer (score 1):

usually stuff like this is handled through include path.

1. Create special place for you files e.g. `/libs/php/`
2. Put your files in there
3. Add include path in your php script `set_include_path(get_include_path(). PATH_SEPARATOR .  '/libs/php/')`;
4. Simply to `require_once` or `include_once` or `include` with relative path to that location

For example if your file is located in `/libs/php/shared/share.php` you need to use `require_once`shared/share.php`

Answer (score 0):

If you have direct access to the server shell, how about using symlinks?

```
ln -s source dest
```

(assuming it's a Linux server).